# Uptime Checks failed in google cloud stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have created uptime checks, but its look failed after every checks and throw an alert every 15 to 20 minutes

Uptime Checks condition

> Violates when: Any
>   metric.type="monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed" AND
>   metric.label.check_id="tcp-****-****-****-22" AND
>   resource.type=one_of("gce_instance", "aws_ec2_instance") stream is
>   above a threshold of 1 for greater than 5 minutes

Comment: Are you getting any specific failure error?

Answer (score 0):

The [metrics list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-monitoring) documents the "uptime_check/check_passed" metric type as "**True if the resource passed the check.**"

Your condition violates when any metric is above 1, which will be true as long as some resource is being checked (whether or not it passes). You want to consider only the streams where the metric is false, for example in the [Uptime Check policy exapmle](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-json#json-uptime) (in JSON) the aggregation includes `REDUCE_COUNT_FALSE`.